# What issues to check for when going from single to multiple users

Tags: database, database-design, filemaker

I have inherited a (rather large) database, which at the moment is only ever accessed by a single user. In the future I want this to be accessible to multiple users at the same time (which can be done using Filemaker Network).

I am concerned that multiple user access may break much of the functionality (for example searches, which change records in tables). What other things should I look out for which could cause multi-user problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches should just be queries - those shouldn't impact other users above/beyond overall performance.

Updates should be reflected across all users - that's the benefit of using filemaker for multiple users. If you need to keep recordsets for distinct users then you will need to look at making significant changes.

Comment: the person who had set up the database had used table entries to filter records (e.g. 1 to display it, 0 to hide) in searches, I think that this will mean the if multiple-users attempt a search it will not work as expected.

Comment: you'd have to script all finds to use a value based on username, ex: when a record is added you should be setting creation user. you then script the find and set the value for creation user to current user (not in a visible field) and then let them enter the other values.